# Update function params

Tags: sql

I want to update 2 input parameters of the function if they are null.
I can update only one. When I try to apply same logic I have error(Must declare the scalar variable)

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc
(
    @input datetime,
    @input2 datetime
)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    if(@input=null)
        SET @input =  cast('1753-1-1' as datetime);
    end

    if(@input2=null)
        SET @input2 = cast('2000-1-1' as datetime);
    end

    RETURN @input;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary to write a "begin" after the first and second if-clause when you write an "end" at the end of the if-clause:

```
..
if(@input=null) begin
    SET @input =  cast('1753-1-1' as datetime);
end

if(@input2=null) begin
    SET @input2 = cast('2000-1-1' as datetime);
end
..
```

This will help to resolve the error.

Also the implicit conversion from datetime to int is not allowed. That's why you have to change the return datatype to datetime after the fix.

Comment: Yes the return type is wrong. I created simple example. Thanks